# 2,3 dimensional solutions to partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE

$ \nabla^2 \phi(\mathbf{r}) = m^2 (\phi(\mathbf{r}) - \phi_0 )$,

where $\mathbf{r} = (x_1, x_2, ... x_n)$

that I need to solve on some domain.

It's easy in a one-dimensional case, as solutions of the form

$\phi(z) = C_0 e^{m z} + C_1 e^{-m z} + \phi_0$

can be seen to work ($C_0$ and $C_1$ are constants to be determined with reference to the boundary conditions, $z$ is the spatial dimension).

However, when I need to generalise to 2 or 3 dimensions (in cartesian coordinates), I can't seem to get it to work. I initially thought something like

$\phi(x,y) = C_0 e^{m x} + C_1 e^{-m x} + C_2 e^{m y} + C_3 e^{-m y} + \phi_0$

would work, but this doesn't work for the physical application of the equation. Is there some other approach that I should be taking?

Comment: As the function only depends on $\mathbf{r}$, you should reformulate the equation in cylindrical or spherical coordinates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Comment: @YvesDaoust As the $\pmb r$ is boldface, I think it stands for the whole vector $\pmb r = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ of coordinates. Never liked this notation, but it is often used ...

Comment: Cylindrical or spherical coordinates aren't appropriate for the geometry and the boundary conditions. By $\mathbf{r}$, I mean a general displacement vector, not just the radial distance.

Comment: @martini - right. I've added some clarification as you say.

Comment: @martini: you are right, my comment is irrelevant.

Comment: This is similar to a Helmholtz type equation (but for the sign), which can be solved by separation of variables for simple geometries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation

Comment: You have to find the Green's function $G(r)$ associated with $m{^2}-∇{^2}$, which can be found in many books. Then $φ(r)=∫dsG(r-s)φ{_0}(s)$. Here $r,s$ should be bold face and the integration is over $R{^n}$.